# formula value changes I want the trigger to update fields

Tags: apex, trigger, formula-field

My trigger fires if I edit/save Account only but I want it to fire once the Contract_End__c == Today_10_Trigger__c. The Today_10_Trigger__c is a formula.
 I'm getting the impression that triggers will not execute on an internal query,if that's the correct phase for a formula field. If this is the case does anyone have a suggestion for me.

**Here's my trigger:**

```
trigger RenewalUpdates on Account (before insert,before update) {

    List<Account > needsUpdate = new List<Account >();  

 for( Account accountId : Trigger.new)
 {
//  if( Trigger.oldMap.get( accountId ).Contract_End__c== Trigger.newMap.get( accountId ).Today_10_Trigger__c)
  if(accountId.Contract_End__c== accountId.Today_10_Trigger__c && accountId.Record_Type_Hidden__c== 'Agent' && accountId.Status__c == 'Active')
  {


        // do something here because your field are equal

        //accountId.End_Date_Trigger__c=system.today();
        accountId.Renewal_In_Progress__c=true;
        accountId.Status__c='Renewal In progress';
        accountId.Approval_Progress__c='Up For renewal';        

        needsUpdate .add(accountId);
        System.debug('Test=============');
  }
}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use a [Workflow with Time-dependent actions](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=workflow_time_action_considerations.htm&language=en_US) or Process Builder with Scheduled Actions. Apex Triggers are only fired on create or edit.

---

***Update***

### Step by step instructions to create Process

**Please read [Process Scheduled Actions Considerations](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=process_limits_scheduled.htm&language=en_US) BEFORE creating your process**

---

- Start `Process Buider` and create new Process
- Select `Account` for the object
- Add Criteria:
  1. You can tick 'Conditions are met', I just did not have custom fields to select from
  2. Have all criteria when time actions have to apply
  3. Do not forget to check 'Yes' in Advanced settings - it enables Scheduled actions

[image: New Criteria]

- Click on 'Set Schedule'
- Recreate as shown in the screenshot (or adjust to your need)

[image: Time trigger]

- Click on 'Add Action' and select 'Update records'
- IMO - you have too many fields representing the same data, I'd recommend only to change the Status here, and have another actions (see next slide) - send email to the owner, or chatter message, and update the other fields later in the process, but this is up to you

[image: Status Update]

- This is where you can add more actions, selection from the available options

[image: More actions]

- A top level overview of the Process you created
- 6 - you could have another scheduled actions - like another Status update when Contract ended. But have to pay attention to entry Criteria: we change the status 10 days before contact end, and when Process criterias will be evaluated after this change, this criteria will return false and any other Scheduled actions here will be deleted.

[image: More time triggers]

Comment: I tried using both options as a simple test. I made sure the 2 fields where equal before creating a WFR and PB. Then when I created both to trigger a simple boolean test. Nothing triggered

Comment: It's not working like that. You have to have activated WF or PB in place, and then trigger records updates, so the rules are evaluated and time-triggered action records or flow interview for PB  will be created. If you could give me some more background on your case, I can guide you. You don't need a formula fields like `Today_10_Trigger__c` as this can be defined in a time-dependent actions - like `10 days from now` or `2 weeks before My_Target_Date__c`

Comment: Sure that would be great, thanks @Oleksiy. I'm more comfortable with PB if you wouldn't mind walking me through the steps to get it working. Keeping in mind that I need this to be automatic. So if I have an account with an end date of April 11th. I need this PB to auto execute on it's own

Comment: This is what `Scheduled Actions` are for )) You have to read the documentation also, as they have some limitations - like you won't be able to modify (e.g. change number of days used to calculate when they trigger) them once you have some time-triggered records created for the rule or PB. I'm going to Edit my answer soon to provide you more details on how to setup.

Comment: There are 4 fields that I'm working with in Person Account Objects (Status__c,Approval_Progress__c,Renewal_In_Progress__c,Contract_End__c) when it's 10 days before Contract_End__c. I want the other fields to be triggered to change (Status__c = "Renewal In Progress",Approval_Progress__c = "Up For Renewal",Renewal_In_Progress__c= True)

Comment: Thank you so much for the clear step by step. I've created the PB using your steps and set 2 test account to April 15th. So I'll see tomorrow is this PB triggers

Comment: You can find out [here how to see all unexecuted scheduled actions](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=process_delete_instance.htm&language=en_US): `From Setup, enter Flows in the Quick Find box, then select Flows.
The Waiting Interviews related list displays any unexecuted scheduled actions in your organization, as well as any waiting flow interviews.`

Comment: That worked perfectly. I could see the flow schedule and it triggered this morning. So now I have contract that are ending April 30th. I'm assuming they will not show in the Flows schedule until the 20th, correct? Thank you for all your help

Comment: correction. only 1 of the 2 test accounts triggered. Can you think of any reason for this. They were both set for April 15th, 2016 end dates, they are both Agent types and Active. The only difference between the 2 are the system create dates. The one that worked was create in 2016 and the other 2015

Comment: I believe I know why. the 1 account was already set to July 15 the other I had to go in and change to July 15. So the one I changed triggered the flow. I just tested that theory by going into the Accounts where the contracts are due April 30th. As soon as I went in and change a field they showed up in the flow. Therefore does this mean that I need to go into every account and change something in order for them to be apart of this trigger and if so is there a bulk change way I can do this.

Comment: UPDATE: I used DemandTools and Bulk changed the Status Field to New then Back to Active. Now all the agents are sitting in the Flows trigger to execute when their Contract end dates meets the criteria. I have a question though. If I alter the PB do I need to do the same thing again?

Comment: Yes, each time you modify the PB you have to trigger somehow your records to reevaluate the new criteria. And you would have to delete all previously scheduled actions that you don't want to occur.

Answer (score 0):

What is your formula referencing? Triggers won't fire if a formula field changes, you'd need to create a trigger that fires when the fields driving the formula are changed.

Answer (score 0):

Formulas are evaluated at time of execution so by using after insert and after update you should have access to the formula values at that time.

Answer (score -1):

Try the below
I don't think salesforce allows comparing the values of two fields. 
Note sure what data type is the field accountId.Today_10_Trigger__c. Assign toa varaible in your for loop and check against that value.

```
trigger RenewalUpdates on Account (before insert,before update) {

    List<Account > needsUpdate = new List<Account >();  
    for( Account accountId : Trigger.new)
    {
        //  if( Trigger.oldMap.get( accountId ).Contract_End__c== Trigger.newMap.get( accountId ).Today_10_Trigger__c)
        String today10Trigger = accountId.Today_10_Trigger__c; 
        if(accountId.Contract_End__c== today10Trigger && accountId.Record_Type_Hidden__c== 'Agent' && accountId.Status__c == 'Active')
        {


            // do something here because your field are equal

            //accountId.End_Date_Trigger__c=system.today();
            accountId.Renewal_In_Progress__c=true;
            accountId.Status__c='Renewal In progress';
            accountId.Approval_Progress__c='Up For renewal';        

            needsUpdate .add(accountId);
            System.debug('Test=============');
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: I believe your statement "I don't think salesforce allows comparing the values of two fields" is completely false as it is written. Salesforce absolutely allows you to compare values. Maybe you were trying to say something different?

Comment: yes I was trying to say something different. To extend what I was trying to say. To compare and THEN fire of a trigger based on the comparison. So on the day that the two fields are equal the trigger is executed on its own.